# Does a report require a thesis?

Tags: academic-writing

As I understand it, a *thesis* is some point to be sustained by argument or proof.

I've been asked to write a report on a class project, and the rubric says that I need a "thesis statement". However, since I'm giving a report on a project—I haven't proved anything—I don't think I need one.

Is there some definition or usage of a thesis that is appropriate in a report?

**UPDATE**: I’ve turned in my report, so an answer to my situation is now moot. I would still like to know whether or not a thesis is generally appropriate for a report.

Comment: While your question is sufficiently general, you actual problem can almost certainly only be solved by those who issued the task.

Comment: As you are going to be graded by your teacher, you will need to ask your teacher for the requirements that you have to fulfill. We cannot guess the opinion of your teacher.

Comment: @Cloudchaser You are indeed correct.  I’ve updated my question to focus on the need for a thesis in a report *in general*.